# Translating チャレンジ

Tags: translation

I have always struggled with translating チャレンジ, which has nuances quite different from the English "challenge". Now I am working on a document which uses this word to a ridiculous amount, "challenging" my ability to find appropriate turns of phrase. In the past, I have used "attack", "go up against", "take on", "move boldly into", "take initiative", and so forth. Here are some samples:

```
社員個人や組織のより積極的なチャレンジを応援する
チャレンジを評価する人事制度改革
チャレンジしやすい制度に改革すると
風土づくりにチャレンジする
```

Any contemporary English that is appropriate for this type of usage?

Comment: take initiative was ok. Otherwise, simply try, give a shot, experience etc...

Comment: All of the alternatives you have listed sound good and natural. The only mental rule I personally have is to explicitly NOT use the word "challenge." The only problem I have had is when a client wants all instances of, e.g., チャレンジ translated with the same English.

Answer (score 3):

Suggestions:

**Disclaimer**: I am not a translator, linguist, teacher or anything like that.  I am just a regular Japanese speaker walking down the street who uses no contractions.

社員個人や組織のより積極的なチャレンジを応援する

"endeavors"? "undertakings"?

チャレンジを評価する人事制度改革

"attempts"? "aspirations"?

チャレンジしやすい制度に改革すると

"to try new things"?

風土づくりにチャレンジする

"to tackle"?  "to approach"?

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries seem to give me "self-challenge" or "trying hard to do something". Perhaps something like perseverance?